# How to use java object in JavaScript engine in java8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, nashorn

I want to use java object in javascript engine but not able to do and getting exception: ***javax.script.ScriptException: :1:11 Expected ; but found <***

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Object map = engine.eval("var HashMap<String,String> = Java.type('java.util.HashMap<String,String>()');" +
                      "var map = new HashMap();" +
                      "map.put('key1', 'value1');" +
                      "map.put('key2', 'value2');" +
                      "map.put('key3', 'value3');" +
                      "map");
            System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code, normally it works.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Object map = engine.eval("var HashMap = Java.type('java.util.HashMap');" +
            "var map = new HashMap();" +
            "map.put('key1', 'value1');" +
            "map.put('key2', 'value2');" +
            "map.put('key3', 'value3');" +
            "map");
System.out.println(map);
```

The problem was in the first line of the script:

```
var HashMap<String,String> = Java.type('java.util.HashMap<String,String>()');
```

instead of

```
var HashMap = Java.type('java.util.HashMap');
```

---

But you also can inject a map to your script and manipulate it on the script like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.getContext().getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE).put ("map", map);
engine.eval("map.put('key1', 'value1');" +
            "map.put('key2', 'value2');" +
            "map.put('key3', 'value3');");
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: so means I can't define like this **HashMap<String,String> = Java.type('java.util.HashMap<String,String>()');**

Comment: I update the answer to purpose another solution to your problem. But if you create the map from the script, i think you cannot specify the type.

Comment: I have confirmation, the concept of generics is not known in Javascript. So **new java.util.HashMap()** is actually the same as **new HashMap<Object, Object>()**.